How to use Bootstrap components in an Angular app without a third party module?
I'm trying to enable Bootstrap 5.3 Tooltips in my Angular 17 app.
In angular.json I've included bootstrap.bundle.min.js, which has PopperJS baked in.
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]

I'm using the example code provided by Bootstrap in the official documentation for enabling the tooltips:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#enable-tooltips
Their code throws an error on line 16 of my app.component.ts file...
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'identity-verification-ui';

  onInit() {
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll(
      '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'
    );
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(
      (tooltipTriggerEl) => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl) // <-- line 16
    );
  }
}

The error is Cannot find name 'bootstrap'. ts (2304).  Obviously, the bootstrap class is not available from app.component.ts.

How do I make new bootstrap available within app.component.ts?  Is app.component.ts not the correct place for enabling Bootstrap components across the entire app?  Is there a more preferable way to do this?
I want to avoid loading jQuery.
I want to avoid using a third-party npm module.

I understand your concern, but there's a good reason why loading the entire bootstrap css and javascript into the main bundle isn't recommended. You require the visitor to download all of jquery, popperjs, bootstrap js/css for components that aren't even visible yet on the landing page. That's why libraries like this one exist. If you don't want to use a library, you could still use the code inside your project directly

Update thanks to Kirkland, that remember me "not use any if you can avoid it" I change declaring as HTMLElement instead of any
if you install @types/bootstrap
npm i @types/bootstrap

Just import only Tooltip in your component
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';

And in ngOnInit
ngOnInit() {
  const tooltips:HTMLElement[]=[].slice.call(
            document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  tooltips.map((x:HTMLElement)=>new Tooltip(x))
}

a stackblitz
Update2 using a directive with a selector like [data-bs-toggle="tooltip"] makes that each element with this attribute become in a "super" element. So we can create:
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';

@Directive({
  selector: '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]',
  standalone: true
})
export class TooltipDirective {
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    new Tooltip(elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}

Each standalone component that import this directive makes that the toolTip work.
To enable it app-wide remove standalone: true and import into @NgModule...
import { TooltipDirective } from './path/to/tooltip.directive';

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    ...
    TooltipDirective,
    ...
  ],
  ...
});


This worked for me.  For anyone else who tries this and runs into any in the ngOnInit() method being blocked by the Typescript rules in their project, replace any with HTMLElement.

@Kirkland, thanks for the advice :)

This solution is limited to the component that has the tooltip.  Is there a way to do this globally, so I don't need to repeat the code in multiple components?

@Kirkland, You can use a directive to give "super power" to your attributes. I update the answer and update the stackblitz using the directive.
